# Append <p> content and [data] tag in javascript function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Basically, what I want to do is edit the function below so that the `<p>` tag includes the content 'loading' and the `<span>` tag has the data-icon attribute in the tag:

```
    <p class="loadingp hidden">
        loading
    </p>
    <span class="loadingspan hidden" data-icon="&#xe022"></span>
```

The function is:

```
$(function(){
    // add the loading div, but mark it as hidden
    var loading = $('<div>', {'class': 'loading hidden'})
    var loadingbg = $('<div>', {'class': 'loadingbg hidden'})
    var loadingp = $('<p>', {'class': 'loadingp hidden'})
    var loadingspan = $('<span>', {'class': 'loadingspan hidden'}).data('icon', '\ue022')
    // append it
    $('div.order').append(loading);
    $('div.loading').append(loadingbg);
    $('div.loadingbg').append(loadingp);
    $('p.loadingp').append(loadingspan);
    // now when we click the button launchg the pop up
    $('button#complete').click(send_to_friend)
});
```

Comment: Cool, so, uh, did you have any trouble making said change?

Comment: Using .data() method, you are not adding attribute data-icon to DOM element but to data object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`text` works as part of the initialization object too.

```
var loadingp = $('<p>', {'class': 'loadingp hidden', text: 'loading'});
var loadingspan = $('<span>', {'class': 'loadingspan hidden', 'data-icon': '\ue022'});
```

You could also have used [the `.text()` function](http://api.jquery.com/text/#text2).

(If that wasn’t your question, I’m not sure what was)